# How can I increase performance of AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

My project entered testing phase.

But I suffered lack of performance, when large dataset over than GigaBytes.

Is there turnable parameters on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

First, You can find installed directory on message of 'initdb'.

```
$ initdb
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "agens".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "ko_KR.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
initdb: could not find suitable text search configuration for locale "ko_KR.UTF-8"
The default text search configuration will be set to "simple".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory /Users/agens/Downloads/pgsql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    ag_ctl -D /Users/agens/Downloads/pgsql/data -l logfile start
```

Second, change current directory to agens data directory.

```
$ cd /Users/agens/Downloads/pgsql/data
```

Finally, you can find buffer size parameter on config file.

```
$ grep shared_buffer postgresql.conf
shared_buffers = 128MB      # min 128kB
#wal_buffers = -1           # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
```

"shared_buffers" parameter is key factor for searching performance.

Suggested buffer size is minimum of whole data and half of system memory.